# How do I make a list of strings withouth invalid characters in any of the strings?

Tags: python

For example, if I had this list of invalid characters:

```
invalid_char_list = [',', '.', '!']
```

And this list of strings:

```
string_list = ['Hello,', 'world.', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer!!']
```

I would want to get this new list:

```
new_string_list = ['Hello', 'world', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer']
```

withouth `,` or `.` or `!` in any of the strings in the list because those are the characters that are in my list of invalid characters.

Comment: To be clearer, what exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. that said, some shape of looping over the strings and removing unwanted chars is probably right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looping through the string_list and replacing each invalid char with an empty string.

```
invalid_char_list = [',', '.', '!']
string_list = ['Hello,', 'world.', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer!!']

for invalid_char in invalid_char_list:
    string_list=[x.replace(invalid_char,'') for x in string_list]

print(string_list)
```

The Output:

```
['Hello', 'world', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` and create this pattern : `[,.!]` and replace with `''`.

```
import re
re_invalid = re.compile(f"([{''.join(invalid_char_list)}])")
# re_invalid <-> re.compile(r'([,.!])', re.UNICODE)

new_string_list = [re_invalid.sub(r'', s) for s in string_list]
print(new_string_list)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'world', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer']
```

- `[.,!]` : Match only this characters `(',', '.', '!')` in the set

Comment: For OP. I think rather than an exclude list, it'll be a lot easier for you to define an allow list of characters rather than a exclude list. Invert the allow list to remove all characters you're not explicitly expecting. `re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", s)`

Comment: @flakes, thanks for your comment, But OP says, he/she has a list of invalid, so I think we should use that `list`, and for now that list have these chars : `, or . or !` but when we write `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` we remove all char except of these: `(a-zA-Z0-9)`

Comment: That's why I upvoted you and only left this as a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

We can loop over each string in string_list and each invalid character and use String.replace to replace any invalid characters with '' (nothing).

```
invalid_char_list = [',', '.', '!']
   string_list = ['Hello,', 'world.', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer!!']
   formatted_string_list = []
   for string in string_list:
       for invalid in invalid_char_list:
           string = string.replace(invalid, '')
       formatted_string_list.append(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip()`:

```
string_list = ['Hello,', ',world.?', 'I', 'am?', '!a,', 'programmer!!?']

new_string_list = [c.strip(',.!?') for c in string_list]

print(new_string_list)

#['Hello', 'world', 'I', 'am', 'a', 'programmer']
```

Comment: This won't work if you have `string_list = ['Python, Monty']`.